# How to send custom data to DataTable server-side processing not from DataTable's filter input?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatable

In my page there is a group of four fields to make custom `search` of records in the database ; the results will be displayed inside a `DataTable` which is displayed below these group of fields :

[image]

Here is the javascript creation of the DataTable :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var j_table = $("#t_list").dataTable( {

        "oLanguage"     : {
                            "sInfoThousands": " ",
                            "sEmptyTable"   : _getText("datatable_resultat_zero", "global"),
                            "sInfo"         : _getText("datatable_zone_statut_info", "global"),
                            "sInfoEmpty"    : "",
                            "sInfoFiltered" : _getText("datatable_zone_statut_filtre", "global"),
                            "sLengthMenu"   : _getText("datatable_zone_nb_affichage", "global"),
                            "sSearch"       : _getText("datatable_zone_filtre", "global"),
                            "sZeroRecords"  : _getText("datatable_resultat_zero", "global"),
                            "oPaginate"     : {
                                                "sPrevious" : _getText("datatable_btn_prcdt", "global"),
                                                "sNext"     : _getText("datatable_btn_svt", "global")
                                              }
                        },

        "sPaginationType"   : "bootstrap",

        "aoColumnDefs": [
                         { "aTargets": [ 3 ], "bSortable": false },
                         { "aTargets": [ 3 ], "bSearchable": false },
                         {
                             "aTargets": [ 3 ],
                             "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                               return '<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="<?php echo site_url('meeting/modif'); ?>/'+data+'" title="Modifier"><button class="btn btn-mini">Detail</button></a></div>';
                             }
                         }
                       ],

        "bServerSide": true,

        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo site_url('ajax/dataTableListerMeetingNotes'); ?>",

        "sServerMethod": "POST"

    } );

});
</script>
```

So how to pass the values entered in the four fields to the ajax source of the `DataTable` when clicking the "Valider" blue button ? And how to collect these data inside the `script` called by the DataTable's `ajax` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [fnServerParams](https://datatables.net/beta/1.9/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html).

Add this to your initialisation code, and every time you call `fnDraw()`, the parameters will be passed in the datatable request.  Obviously you'll have to change the jquery selectors to match your input Ids.

```
"sServerMethod": "POST",
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
    aoData.push({ "name": "sujet", "value": $('#Sujet').val() });
    aoData.push({ "name": "lieu", "value": $('#Lieu').val() });
    aoData.push({ "name": "dateDu", "value": $('#DateDu').val() });
    aoData.push({ "name": "dateAu", "value": $('#DateAu').val() });
},
```

In the `Valider` button click event you call `j_table.fnDraw()`

On the server side, you access the parameters in the same way as the standard datatables parameters, ie get the from the querystring:

```
$_POST['sujet']
```

I'm not familiar with PHP but It'll be something like that.